# Does having a B1/B2 help your case for a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen

I'm planning on applying for a Schengen visa to travel to Europe for vacation. I was told by this agency that having a B1/B2 USA visa sort of guarantees the issuing of the Schengen visa and that the application procedure is not as strict. I want to know if anyone has any idea how true this is.

I want to know how many documents I have to provide (they give several types of documents that are accepted as proof, etc), if just 1 of each type would suffice, since the agency mentioned that the application procedure is not too strict, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Oscar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't count on that to the extent of submitting less documentation than you would otherwise.

The various Schengen countries are supposed to follow a common rule set when deciding visa applications, but the rules are phrased very generically and leave a lot of room for being applied in different ways by different consular services. The few hard rules there are don't mention anything about visitor visas for the USA influencing the decision, so a blanket claim that all Schengen consulates will react to them in the same way is almost certainly false.

What *is* generally true is that the *same facts* about you and your circumstances that made you qualify for a US visa are *also* likely to make you qualify for a Schengen visa, since they look for broadly the same things. So document them with the same care you did when you applied for the US visa.

It would be different if you had *legal residence* in the US -- that would make it less likely that you're going to overstay and become an illegal immigrant, since most people would prefer to be legal in the US over being illegal in Europe.

But a mere visitor visa will not have this effect. That only gives you the same opportunity to immigrate illegally to the US that you would get in Europe. And most European consular officers would easily be able to think of reasons why you would prefer being an illegal immigrant in their country over being an illegal immigrant in America.

Comment: I just recently cancelled my visa application. I strictly followed the procedure, but for some reason the embassy wanted me to send some documents that were already in my application. That was not the problem, problem was that they sent the request to an email that has nothing to do with the one I provided in my application. And they weren't even careful enough to try and reach me in any other way. So my application was sitting there for over a week and I only found out there was a prob because my passport was due to be back yesterday and when I went to pick it up  it wasn't there.